# How to get each column values from Object array stored in list

Tags: java

I have stored `String` values in `Object` array. Once I am done, I have added the object into list, and when I am trying to get stored values from list, I am getting only the last row. I have used enhanced for loop with `Object` array as data type and list in right side.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

public class ReportOne{
public static String input_path = ("C:\\Users\\RAVI\\Desktop\\Skills\\inputs");
public static String output_path = ("C:\\Users\\RAVI\\Desktop\\Skills\\outputs");
static BufferedReader br;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:MM.ss");
    SimpleDateFormat parsingSdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:MM.ss a");
    ArrayList<Object[]> list= new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    Object[] received = new Object[3];
        try{
            File fi = new File(input_path);
            File[] fileCount = fi.listFiles();
            for(int i = 0;i<fileCount.length;i++){
                File file = fileCount[i];
                if(file.isFile()){
                    System.out.println("Total file count : "+fileCount.length);
                    String fileName = file.getName();
                    System.out.println("File name : "+fileName);
                    String data;
                    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(input_path+"\\"+fileName));
                    while((data = br.readLine())!=null){
                        if(data.contains(">")){
                            String dat = data.substring(data.indexOf(" ")+1,data.indexOf("-")-1);
                            //System.out.println(dat);
                            Date date = sdf.parse(dat.substring(dat.indexOf(" "),dat.lastIndexOf(".")));
                            //System.out.println(date);
                            String timeFormat = parsingSdf.format(date);
                            //System.out.println(timeFormat);
                            received[0] = dat.substring(dat.indexOf("0"),dat.indexOf(" ")+1)+timeFormat;
                            //System.out.println(received[0]);
                            received[1] = data.substring(data.indexOf("<")+1,data.indexOf(",")-1);
                            //System.out.println(received[1]);
                            received[2] = data.substring(data.indexOf("Target"),data.lastIndexOf("."));
                            //System.out.println(received[2]);
                            list.add(received);
                        }
                    }

                }

            }

            for(Object[] data : list){
                System.out.println("-->  " +data[0]+" "+data[1]+" "+data[1]);
                //Unable to get all datas it is printing only last row from file
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            }
        }
```

Sample input

```
(14581907) 06/29/2013 09:11.11.594 -->Successful password change for user=<U098095>, Password Target=<DOW>.
(14856413) 06/30/2013 21:39.35.837 -->Successful password change for user=<U545711>, Password Target=<a19mvs.nam.dow.com>.
(14858306) 06/30/2013 21:55.14.121 -->Successful password change for user=<NG34811>, Password Target=<a19mvs.nam.dow.com>.
```

Output

```
-->  06/30/2013 09:07.14 PM NG34811 NG34811
-->  06/30/2013 09:07.14 PM NG34811 NG34811
-->  06/30/2013 09:07.14 PM NG34811 NG34811
```

Expected output is instead of printing last row values thrice from input file need to get actual values in each line from file.

Comment: Firstly, you have data[1] twice in the for loop print - is that correct?

Comment: Yes, i have and all the values i am able to get from file, only issue i am facing is while getting from list which holds all the values as object to be exact in the end of try block i have used enhanced for loop to print that's where i couldn't figure it out @JGFMK rest all working fine

Comment: Wouldn't you need 0,1 and 2 - not 0, 1 and 1?

Comment: i need received[0], 1 and 2 @JGFMK and i got to know just now about the declaration of arraylist which should be inside while loop then only it creates new object whenever new values arrive while splitting the string from file

Comment: You probably had multiple issues there - but I immediately spotted the one I mentioned.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you are referring to, can you please mention more specific which one you spotted ..?

Comment: `for(Object[] data : list){
                System.out.println("-->  " +data[0]+" "+data[1]+" "+data[1]);` I presume this corresponds to the received[0], ... 1 ... 2

Comment: Yes, i am aware of that..but what you trying to say..?

Comment: Open your eyes data[1] twice.. Please no more!

Comment: You have to open your eyes to see what is really happening, please leave me at peace

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize your object 'received'  each time when adding into arraylist.

ie put your Object[] received = new Object[3]; inside if statement

Comment: There's more than one `if` statement. It would need to go inside the innermost one.

Comment: Thanks much ..!! Yes it is worked out why i got this issue in first place what is wrong in decaring it common use when is necessary,

Comment: By creating `received` just once, you are simply over-writing the same array with for each input line and adding multiple references to it into `list`.  It ends up _looking like_ three entries that happen to all look like the last line; it's really three references to the exact same array object, and the array got successively overwritten by each line of input so they all end up looking like the last input.

Comment: i got expected output but why can't declare out side while loop actually i placed inside while loop and out side of if and its worked out, i guess it wont make any difference , does it..? @Shyni

Comment: You can _declare_ where you've already got the declaration now.  The key is to assign a `new Object[3]` to it before starting to work on each new input line, so that you're not re-using the same object array for all your inputs.

Comment: Thanks for the perfect explanation but you have mentioned about received which is reference of arraylist which is gotta go inside if loop right but i have declared inside while loop and it is working just fine. what makes difference @KevinAnderson

Comment: I only suggested moving the declaration inside the innermost `if` because that's closest to where you actually use `received`.  But really, as long as you're assigning it a `new Object[3]` inside the `while` statement that's looping over your input (could be in the `if`, could be before...), you're golden,

Comment: Thanks a lot @KevinAnderson appreciate your time, to explain exactly what i need, it's really useful for me to practice more and learn more in java, i am a beginner and the comments you have added is valuable to me.

Comment: Of course i did changed again and declared list inside if loop which is best way where i am exactly adding